Is there some source relating real poisons with ad&d (1e/2e) poison chart?
2e Dmg text for 'Table 51: Poison Strength' is clear:

Poisons are not listed by name here, since this is neither a
scientific text nor a primer on the deadly nature of many plants and
animals.

But maybe some of them are inspired on real poisons. Is there some interview or any other source (official or not) about possible relation?

I don't believe so, as far as the Dragon magazine archives go.
The use of poison charts similar to the one in the 2e DMG seems to have been introduced in an article by Charles Sagui, titled "Poisons from AA to XX", published in The Dragon magazine issue 32 (December 1979). The article itself is being introduced at the beginning of the magazine as follows:

This month we have several D&D related articles, on a variety of
subjects. Charles Sagui gives us: Poison: from AA to XX. Although the use of poison in D&D campaigns is generally discouraged, this article presents a guide for allowing the presence of poison while restricting its use by players.

This seems to imply that we were getting new material that was not necessarily based on any earlier information. The article introduces the letter-style poison classification as follows:

Alchemists learn to make poison at one strength per level of experience up to the fifth, beginning with level 0, strength “AA.” At sixth level an Alchemist can make strength “S” sleep poison that may be sold to any class or type. After sixth level he learns one strength for each two experience levels the alchemist attains through strength “J” at level 16. Type “X” may be manufactured only by an Alchemist of 20th level and type “XX” only by 25th level and above. Alchemists through level 4 may make only ingested poisons; through 8th level they may make ingested plus water-soluble poison; and through 16th level they may also produce contact-type poison, including poison gas.

The article provides no connections at all to actual poisons.
Alchemists themselves were introduced in an article by Jon Pickens published in Dragon issue 2 (August 1976, OD&D). The article did not specify any classifications for poisons. It only stated:

Poisons: Alchemists may brew potions of a strength level equal to their own experience levels. Each strength level costs 50GP and one day.

The closest we get to a connection to "actual" poison types is in a "D&D Variant" short piece by Bill Coburn (Dragon #18, September 1978). It describes three categories only, A (potion form: arsenic, hemlock, etc.), B (gas, darts, cobras, needles that can deliver a neurotoxin) and C (hemotoxins from spiders, scorpions, p. worms, other snakes, wyverns etc.). However, this variant does not seem to have been picked up as a basis for the 2e DMG.

Confirming Bill Coburn's text at page 20. Very interesting. I remember an unofficial book in pdf format made by players probably, where I think one of the topics was poisons. I don't know if they tried to stabilish some link or just adapted the real poisons separately.

A friend of mine gave me a link (not a relation with the table, but we can found some unnoficial adaptation of real poisons): https://www.ahazu.com/adnd/netbooks.php
